Splitting R string based on multiple criteria (data does not have a simple delineation like spaces or comma to separate by)
I have a dataset where each row is a character string like this (and this is all under one column):
Jacoby BrissettO 206.5-115U 206.5-115Joe BurrowO 243.5-115U 243.5-155.
I want to split this into rows and columns like so:



Name
O/U Line




Jacoby Brissett
206.5


Joe Burrow
243.5



I can post specific code if needed, but this illustrates my exact problem pretty much, so you can type the example character string and try to fix it yourself in R. I've looked everywhere for a solution to this, but most similar questions are easily solvable by separating by commas or spaces, which as you can see, is pretty impossible in this case.
I tried using the separate tidyverse function, the gsub function, the str_remove function, and the str_split_fixed function. I can't figure out the parameters to make any of these work, and I don't even know if these functions would have worked, which doesn't help me very much.

We assume that

a digit followed immediately by an upper case letter followed immediately by a lower case letter should have a newline inserted after the digit.

O followed immediately by space separates the name and the value and

everything after the minus is to be omitted


Then we can use this code:
Lines <- "Jacoby BrissettO 206.5-115U 206.5-115Joe BurrowO 243.5-115U 243.5-155."

Lines |>
  gsub("(\\d)([A-Z][a-z])", "\\1\n\\2", x = _) |>
  gsub("O ", ",", x = _) |>
  read.table(text = _, sep = ",", comment = "-", col.names = c("Name", "Value"))

giving
             Name Value
1 Jacoby Brissett 206.5
2      Joe Burrow 243.5

Added
Some additional data was added in a comment.  We run it on that as well it seems to work there too.
Lines <- c("Jacoby BrissettO 206.5-115U 206.5-115Joe BurrowO 243.5-115U 243.5-155.",
"Gardner MinshewO 255.5-115U 255.5-115Justin HerbertO 150.5-115U 150.5-115",
"Bo NixO 140.5-115U 140.5-115Geno SmithO 137.5-115U 137.5−115")

Lines |>
  gsub("(\\d)([A-Z][a-z])", "\\1\n\\2", x = _) |>
  gsub("O ", ",", x = _) |>
  read.table(text = _, sep = ",", comment = "-", col.names = c("Name", "Value"))

giving
             Name Value
1 Jacoby Brissett 206.5
2      Joe Burrow 243.5
3 Gardner Minshew 255.5
4  Justin Herbert 150.5
5          Bo Nix 140.5
6      Geno Smith 137.5


Thank you so much-- this is extremely helpful. Do you have any idea how I could make a function so I can apply this over a list of strings, like: [1] "Gardner MinshewO 255.5−115U 255.5−115Justin HerbertO 150.5−115U 150.5−115"
[2] "Bo NixO 140.5−115U 140.5−115Geno SmithO 137.5−115U 137.5−115" etc. etc.? Or a table where each of these character strings is a row? Thank you!

It already does that for a character vector of strings. for example, if Lines <- c(Lines, Lines) then it still works giving 4 rows.

Huh, when I do it I get "Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : line 1 did not have 2 elements" maybe because one element in the vector contains only one quarterback and respective line. I'll see if I can fix that, or maybe just find a website that has all the lines (I don't know why they're missing one QB, very annoying).

I have added the data in your comment in the Added section and it works there too.  Note that when I copied it the minus signs in it were actually characters that looked like minus signs but were something else so I replaced them with minus signs. That may or may not be in your actual data or it might just be a problem in copying the data to and from the web.  At any rate, I did not get any errors so if you have data that you haven't shown that does not follow the pattern of the data you have shown there is not much anyone can say without it.
